# MySQL Alter table add column with default of 1

Tags: mysql

I have read most of the posts concerning MySQL ALTER TABLE but can't find an answer to my issue.

I have a script that adds a new column to a table, this works fine but the issue I have is it is not setting the default value for the new column. Am I missing something:

```
ALTER TABLE Hist ADD S1 VARCHAR( 5 ) DEFAULT '1', ADD comments_S1 TEXT
```

The above is the code I am using.

Any idea's

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: seems like something in Your application code sets S1 field to empty string

Answer (score 1):

Alas, the `default` value gets used only for new rows.  The old rows get `NULL`.  So, simply update them after the alter table:

```
update hist
    set s1 = '1';
```

This is not really well [documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) in MySQL, but it is sort-of suggested . .

> Alterations that modify only table metadata and not table data are
>   immediate because the server only needs to alter the table .frm file,
>   not touch table contents. The following changes are fast alterations
>   that can be made this way:
>
> . . .
>   - Changing the default value of a column (except for NDB tables).

Adding a column *does* require a table copy.  But the old values are not affected.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the syntax for adding a column to a MySQL table is:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN col type DEFAULT 'default';
```

You are missing the keyword `COLUMN` from your syntax.  Try the following:

```
ALTER TABLE Hist
ADD S1 VARCHAR(5) DEFAULT '1',
ADD comments_S1 TEXT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something in Your application code sets S1 field to empty string.

```
ALTER TABLE Hist
ADD S1 VARCHAR(5) DEFAULT '1' NOT NULL,
ADD comments_S1 TEXT;
```

it will prevent S1 from being empty and automatically change `NULL` fields to `'1'`